# How to install man pages for certain libc functions?

Tags: debian, man, glibc, bsd, development

In the past, from time to time, while developing Linux software, I have noticed that some `man` pages which deal with developer documentation are missing on my systems.

This happens mainly on Debian systems. For example, yesterday I needed to use the `fls()` function, but `man fls` did not lead to anywhere, and despite researching and trying this and that, I still have no idea what I could do to install those missing `man` pages.

I believe that this problem is related to the fact that some functions which are available originally have been implemented on other platforms (for example, `fls()` seems to come from `BSD`. However, this finding did not help; there is no special `POSIX` or `BSD` developer documentation in Debian (at least, I couldn't find it).

Until now, I have worked around the problem by googling for `man xxx`, which worked (i.e. let me find the respective `man` page) every time. But this is crude and unsatisfying and makes me dependent on online services, so I think it's time to solve the problem.

How to install all of such documentation in recent Debian versions (notably the man pages which are *not* in the package `glibc-doc`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should install [`manpages-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/manpages-dev), which provides manpages for system calls and a number of library functions, and the `-dev` and (if any) `-doc` packages for the libraries you’re developing with.

For kernel functions you should install [`linux-manual-4.9`](https://packages.debian.org/linux-manual-4.9) (or whichever version is appropriate); this is where you’ll find `man 9 fls`.

To find manpages in general, install `apt-file`, update the indexes (`apt update`), then search for the manpage you want:

```
apt-file search -x man./fls\\.
```

(the `-x` option tells `apt-file` to interpret the argument as a Perl regex).

Comment: I see. Wouldn't have come to that idea. So `ffs()`, which logically belongs to the same function group (these functions return the highest or lowest set bit in an integer value) is in the normal documentation of `glibc`, while `fls()` is in the kernel documentation *although* its `man` page is titled "Basic C library functions". This is completely weird. However: problem solved, answer accepted.

Comment: The `fls` manpage title is misleading, `fls` is a function available in the kernel, not in the C library. (On Linux at least.)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `manpages-dev` package, on Ubuntu at least there's also `manpages-posix` and `manpages-posix-dev`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, and +1. While @Stephen Kitt mentioned `manpages-dev`, I still didn't know about the two others yet. I'll examine whether they exist on Debian, too, which is likely because Ubuntu is derived from Debian.